# Unblending a alpha blend

Tags: javascript, math, colors

Hoping to get a bit of help with a unblending a alpha blend

I have this function

```
    function mix(color1, color2, alpha)
    {
      let temp = {};
      temp.r = Math.round( alpha * color2.r + (1 - alpha) * color1.r );
      temp.g = Math.round( alpha * color2.g + (1 - alpha) * color1.g );
      temp.b = Math.round( alpha * color2.b + (1 - alpha) * color1.b );
      return temp;
    }
```

If I run this i get a new color "{r: 128, g: 0, b: 128}"

```
color1 = {r:255, g:0, b:0},
color2 = {r:0,   g:0, b:255},
new_color = mix(color1, color2, .5); "{r: 128, g: 0, b: 128}"
```

Is it possible to retrieve color1 ({r:255, g:0, b:0}) from calculating color2, new_color and the alpha.

Here is an example https://codepen.io/-cheese/pen/WNwqzZG

Any help with this would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could get an estimation, since you round the result of the blended color and you do not have the exact data:

```
 function unmix(new_color, some_color, alpha){
      let temp = {};
      temp.r = Math.min((new_color.r - (alpha * some_color.r)) / (1 - alpha),255);
      temp.g = Math.min((new_color.g - (alpha * some_color.g)) / (1 - alpha),255);
      temp.b = Math.min((new_color.b - (alpha * some_color.b)) / (1 - alpha),255);
      return temp;
 }
```

You can test it by adding the code below in the code you provided:

```
old_color_1 = unmix(new_color, color2, .5)
console.log(old_color_1);
```

This will return:

```
{
  b: 1,
  g: 0,
  r: 255
}
```

Notice that `b` value is returned as `1` and not `0` as it should, that's because of the rounding function you're using. The formula used in order to calculate one of the original colors if you take the equation below:

```
new_color.r = alpha * color2.r + (1 - alpha) * color1.r
```

and isolate `color1.r` to create a new one.

Comment: Thanks so much that was exactly what I was looking for